# How to keep track of already processed files in hdfs in spark

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs

So I have a spark job that runs every hour. The job processes files
from HDFS. So what I need to know is there an efficient way to keep track of those files in HDFS that are already processed. Files cannot be moved/deleted/renamed

What I tried is store all file names in a map along with their last modified time and store the last entry of the map somewhere (Say /user/xyz -> 159283742893472 is my last entry of the map) and so when the job starts again I can use the stored details and process only those beyond 159283742893472 (159283742893472 is the time in millis)

```
FileStatus[] fileStatusArray = fileSystem.listStatus(newPath(path));

for (FileStatus fileStatus : fileStatusArray) {
    long modificationTime =fileStatus.getModificationTime();
    filesMap.put(fileStatus.getPath().getName(), modificationTime);
}
```

Expectation is to avoid reprocessing of already processed files

Comment: have you considered keep track in an audit table, preferably hbase or something oriented with unitary access/read ?

Comment: Best practice here would be to move files after they've been processed. I know you say you can't, but it's weird to have a folder containing processed and unprocessed data. Otherwise @kulssaka is right, you should use something like HBase.